# Nightmare and loop method to extract data

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, nightmare

I wand to grab all links from site using Nightmare npm. Then go over each link and grab title and text body.
I have this code, it works fine when i pass single link, but when i want loop through result of first function i get an error with emmit.setMaxListeners[]... Thanks for any help.

```
function getUrls1() {
  var n = new Nightmare()
  .goto('http://www.example.com/newslist')
  .evaluate(function () {
    var arr = [];
     $('.news4 dd > a').each(function (i) {
      arr.push({link: $(this).prop('href')})
    })
    return arr;
  }).run(function (err,result) {
    // here i have an array of obj with prop link
    // but i need to loop over each link
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(result[0].link);
    getText(result[0].link);
  });
}

function getText(link) {
  var n = new Nightmare()
    .goto(link)
    .evaluate(function () {
       return {
         title: $('h1.title').text(),
         text: $('div.text').text()
       };
    }).run(function (err,result) {
      // here i can write file or do something else
      if(err) console.error(err);
      console.log(result);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an older question, but this was fixed* in [PR #407](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/pull/407), which was released in a new version shortly after.

<sub>* - the event emitter maximum is set to `Infinity`.  See issue [#282](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/282) for more details.</sub>